# how can I write a double group bys query

Tags: sql

I have the following table with the following columns

```
payments

recipient_id, sender_id, amount
```

I want to sum up the amounts for each id

like the following

```
select -sum(amount) from payments group by sender_id 
select sum(amount) from payments group by recipient_id
```

that gives me the amount removed from each sender account and the amount added from each recipient's account.

how can I combine those two queries into one query so that I can get the amounts for both the recipient and sender ids? Note that sender_id and recipient_id might overlap. Like a recipient can be a sender in the other query for another transaction. Note that if its a sender the amount is negative, and if its recipient, the amount must be positive. (senders lose money, recipients get money)

so basically if I have the following data

```
recipient_id  sender_id  amount
1              2         50
2              3         100
2              4         150
3              1         50
```

I should get the following result

```
account_id, amount
1               0
2               200   (sent 50, got 250)
3               -50    ( sent 100, got 50)
4               -150  (sent 150 dollars)
```

Comment: If you want to display them side by side, you need to know how they relate to one another.  Do you just want it grouped by all the times X sender sent to Y recipient?

Comment: What is the database system?  mysql?  SQL Server?  Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I think this might work:

```
select (case when recipient_id < sender_id then recipient_id else sender_id end) as id1,
       (case when recipient_id < sender_id then sender_id else recipient_id end) as id2,
       sum(case when recipient_id < sender_id then amount else - amount end) as netamount
from payments
group by (case when recipient_id < sender_id then recipient_id else sender_id end),
         (case when recipient_id < sender_id then sender_id else recipient_id end);
```

It reports generically on pairs of ids, with the smaller being first.  It adds amounts where the smaller id is the recipient and subtracts amounts where the smaller id is the sender.

This assumes that any given transaction appears once in the data.

Comment: I use constructs of this sort regularly, so it definitely should wor (barring a syntax error I cannot see).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can write this query using a CTE.  Select the amounts twice from the table using a positive amount for recipients and a negative amount for senders:

```
;with Transactions (ID, amount) as
(
    select sender_id, -amount
    from Payments
    union all
    select recipient_id, amount
    from Payments
)
select ID as Account_ID, sum(amount) as Amount
from Transactions
group by ID
```

Tested with the following code:

```
if object_id('Payments') is null
begin
    create table Payments
    (
        recipient_id int,
        sender_id int,
        amount int
    )
    insert into Payments (recipient_id, sender_id, amount)
    select 1, 2, 50
    union select 2, 3, 100
    union select 2, 4, 150
    union select 3, 1, 50
end
```

Results:

```
Account_ID Amount
1          0
2          200
3          -50
4          -150
```

The problem with this approach is that it scans the Payments table twice.  Here is another approach using `CROSS APPLY` that goes through the table once:

```
select ID as Account_ID, sum(Transactions.amount) as Amount
from Payments p
    cross apply
    (
        values
        (p.recipient_id, p.amount),
        (p.sender_id, -p.amount)
    ) as Transactions (ID, amount)
group by ID
```

Results:

```
Account_ID Amount
1          0
2          200
3          -50
4          -150
```